# BlueZ missing RequestAuthorization

Tags: linux, bluez

I have a Bluetooth client which implements an agent with `NoInputNoOutput` capabilities (using BlueZ version 5.54 in Linux).

When a new pairing occurs, I expect the agent to receive a RequestAuthorization dbus message, but this never arrives.

From the [BlueZ agent-api documentation](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/doc/agent-api.txt)

> void RequestAuthorization(object device)
>
> This method gets called to request the user to            authorize an
> incoming pairing attempt which            would in other circumstances trigger
> the just-works            model, or when the user plugged in a device that
> implements cable pairing. In the latter case, the           device would
> not be connected to the adapter via           Bluetooth yet.
>
> ```
>       Possible errors: org.bluez.Error.Rejected
>                        org.bluez.Error.Canceled
> ```

I have used `dbus-monitor --system` to check for the existence of the message but it's not there.

Can anyone suggest why this wouldn't be sent?

Comment: Using `NoInputNoOutput` triggers the `Just Works` pairing mode. See "mapping of the IO Capabilities to Key Generation Method" at the bottom of https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-pairing-part-2-key-generation-methods/ . Try changing the capability and see if it gets triggered then.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a way to set up pairing in Bluez which doesn't require a passcode or pin, but allows pairing to be accepted or rejected programmatically?